# i can't undestand why the checkcs50 are saing ":( speller compiles expected exit code 0, not 2" someone can explain?

Tags: c, cs50

I would be relly glad if anyone can help to find what I'm doing wrong. I alread read in other forum that maybe is because somo change in speller code.
But, only the "new" things that I add was the function and the global pointer. I can't undertand why checkcs50 are tell me;

```
:) dictionary.c, dictionary.h, and Makefile exist
:( speller compiles
    expected exit code 0, not 2
:| handles most basic words properly
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| handles min length (1-char) words
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| handles max length (45-char) words
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| handles words with apostrophes properly
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| spell-checking is case-insensitive
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| handles substrings properly
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| program is free of memory errors
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
   char word[LENGTH + 1];
   struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;
// Hash table
node *table[N];

// i created that
node *fre;

// i created that function
void unl(int i, node *tmp);

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
   node *midle;
midle -> next = table[13];
   // TODO
     unsigned int w = hash(word);
     node * tmp = table[w];
     if (w > 12)
     {
         tmp = midle;
     }
     if (tmp == NULL)
     {
         return false;
     }

     while (tmp != NULL)
     {
         if (strcmp(tmp -> word, word) == 0)
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             tmp = tmp->next;
         }
     }



   return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
   unsigned int index_hash = 0;
   int c = word[0];

   if ((90 - c) >= 0)
   {
       return (90 - c);
   }
   else
   {
       return (122 - c);
   }


}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
   FILE * text;
   text = fopen(dictionary,"r");

   if (text == NULL)
   {
       fclose(text);
       return false;
   }

   char buffer[46];
   while (fscanf (text, "%s",buffer) != EOF)
   {
       char * word = buffer;
       unsigned int index_hash = hash(word);

       if (table[index_hash] == NULL)
       {
           node * n = malloc(sizeof(node));
           if (n == NULL)
           {
               return false;
           }
           table[index_hash] = malloc(sizeof(node));
           if (table[index_hash] == NULL)
           {
               return false;
           }
           // talvez ter que colocar o '&' no n
           table [index_hash] -> next = n;
           strcpy(n -> word, word);
           n -> next = NULL;
       }
       else
       {
           node * n  = malloc(sizeof(node));
           if (n == NULL)
           {
               return false;
           }
           int c= 0;
           while (n -> next != NULL)
           {
               c++;
           }
           for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
           {
               if (i == c-1)
               {
                   strcpy(n -> word,word);
                   n -> next = NULL;
               }
           }

       }
   }
   return true;


   // TODO

}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
   int size_loaded = 0;
   int size_loaded_sp = 0;

     node * tmp = table[0];
     node * tmp_midle = table[22];
     if (tmp == NULL)
     {
         return 0;
     }
     if (tmp_midle == NULL)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     while (tmp != NULL && tmp_midle != NULL)
     {
         if (tmp != NULL)
         {
             size_loaded++;
             tmp = tmp->next;
         }
         if (tmp_midle != NULL)
         {
             size_loaded_sp++;
             tmp_midle = tmp_midle-> next;
         }

     }
   // TODO
   return (size_loaded + size_loaded_sp);
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
   node *tmp;
   int j = 0;
   //usar esse while pra recursividade usando esse fre

       // talvez eu deva por uma funçao e usar recursividade
   for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++)
   {
       tmp = table[i];
       while (tmp != NULL)
       {
           tmp = tmp -> next;
           j++;
       }
       for (int k = 0; k > j; k++)
       {
           if (fre == NULL)
           {
               unl(i,tmp);
           }
           else
           {
               tmp = fre;
               unl(i,tmp);
           }
       }
   }

   // TODO
   return false;
}
void unl(int i, node *tmp)
{
   free(tmp);
   tmp = table[i];

   while (tmp != NULL)
       {
           fre = tmp;
           tmp = tmp -> next;
       }

}```
````

Comment: Did you know there is a CS50 Beta StackExchange site with questions like [recover.c: expected exit code 0, not 2?](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/26897/recover-c-expected-exit-code-0-not-2)

Comment: This is a different problem than the one cited for recover. Are you using the CS50 IDE? Did you execute `make` to compile?

Comment: I already solve this problem.For compile speller, i needed use make to compile dictionary.c and speller.c for mikefile could do its job. Olso i solved  broblems that appeaed with my code, as i can see them, when speller compile in chekcs50. Tank you @DinoCoderSaurus

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't change anything in `speller.c` and in `dictionary.h`. I had made this mistake, and this was the cause of that error.